# TextField is not moved back down with keyboard avoidance on

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Does any know what I've done wrong here?

**Problem**

When I tap on the text field and the keyboard appears. Tap on the navgation link to get to the second screen. Then go back, the text field has not returned to the "non-focused" position.

- iOS: 16
- Sim: iPhone 14 Pro

**Expectation**

I am expecting to see the text field back at its original starting place. That is, when I tap the field, the keyboard avoidance causes that field to move up. Then I tap return on the keyboard to dismiss the keyboard, the text field returns to its starting position. When I navigation between view, I expect the same behaviour because the keyboard has been dismissed.

**Steps**

- Tap the textField (assuming software keyboard is on)
- Tap the navigationLink
- Tap Back

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = "Hello, world!"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Hello", destination: { Text("World") })

                TextField("Whoops", text: $text)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work for me when running Xcode 14.1 beta 3 intel with iOS 16.1 on iPhone 14 Pro, i.e. TextField in no KB position on popping nav stack. Some ambiguity on version of iOS problem being reported against - so perhaps fix is just to update. Sure been tried, but if still stuck will mention for completeness, occasionally simulator weirdness can be fixed by resetting the virtual device- or if lucky - just restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Try hide keyboard first and then navigate to the destination as following : -

```
    @State private var text: String = "Hello, world!"
    @State var action : Int? = 0

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("World"), tag: 1, selection: $action) {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
            
            Button {
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to:nil, from:nil, for:nil)
                action = 1
            } label: {
                Text("Hello")
            }
            TextField("Whoops", text: $text)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the focus of your textField before pushing another View. Since iOS 15 we can user @FocusState which does exactly that:

```
@State private var text: String = "Hello, world!"

@State private var pushView:Bool = false
@FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

 var body: some View {
     NavigationView {
             VStack {
                 Button {
                     isFocused = false
                     pushView = true
                 } label: {
                     Text("Hello")
                 }

                 NavigationLink(isActive: $pushView) {
                     Text("World")
                 } label: {
                     EmptyView()
                 }

                 TextField("Whoops", text: $text).onSubmit {
                     pushView = true
                 }.focused($isFocused)
             }
            
     }
 }
```

As for the Still view you can try implementing `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)`